# IJCADのツールパレットのタブが折りたたまれた状態でタブを切り替える方法

Tags: .net, ijcad

IJCAD 2019の.NET APIを利用してツールパレットを作成しています。
ツールパレットに複数のタブが存在している場合に、ツールパレットの小さくしたときにタブを別のタブへ切り替えることができません。
本来ならタブ切り替えのコンテキストメニューが表示されるはずですが、メニューが表示されない為、別のタブへ切り替えることができません。
タブ切り替えのメニューを表示するためのオブションが.NET APIにあれば教えてください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ちなみに、AutoCADで同様のプログラムで確認したところメニューが表示されることを確認しました。

Answer (score 1):

IJCAD 2019とAutoCAD 2019で試してみましたが、確かにそうなりますね。
気になって色々調べてみたのですが、.NETのPaletteSetクラスにはタブ切り替えのコンテキストメニューを出させるオプションが無くて、タブ切り替えをできるような機能もないと思います。
おそらくIJCAD自体の問題な気がします...
お力になれず申し訳ないです。

Comment: ご確認ありがとうございます。
IJCADの問題のような気がしていましたが、やはりそうなのですね...